# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range from tableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have error says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range".
on

```
cell.titleLabel.text = cellDataArrayPoster[indexPath.row].jobTitlePoster as? String
```

please notice that I'm using two different cells,
as prototypeCells. Moreover, they both have different identifier.
both arrays have getting their data from firebase.

```
var cellDataArray = [cellData]()
var cellDataArrayPoster = [cellDataPoster]()


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   return cellDataArray.count + cellDataArrayPoster.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let index = indexPath.row

    if index == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! infoCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = cellDataArray[indexPath.row].jobTitle as? String
        cell.companyLabel.text = cellDataArray[indexPath.row].companyName
        //cell.timeStampLabel.text = cellDataArray[indexPath.row].createdAt.calenderTimeSinceNow()

        return cell

    } else  {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellPoster", for: indexPath) as! infoCellPoster
        cell.titleLabel.text = cellDataArrayPoster[indexPath.row].jobTitlePoster as? String
        //cell.timeStampLabel.text = cellDataArray[indexPath.row].createdAt.calenderTimeSinceNow()
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to use two different sections - one for each of the two arrays of data and types of cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the concept of table view delegate methods. It is good to read more from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview).

My general rule of thumb is to always use only 1 array as data source for table view to avoid index out of range situations.

In your particular case the error is saying all about it - you are trying to reach index number that is out of range of the array. The easiest workaround will be to combine the two arrays in one, and have some sort of inheritance between the objects so they can fit.

Comment: Thanks !! , I just combined the data that two array have it into one array. and it's working good now ! . :)))